# Custom Angular button component needs to fire event

Tags: angular, button, rxjs, reactive

**TL;DR:** I have created a button component in Angular and I want to utilise the best practice reactive behaviour in this button firing behaviour in whichever component decides to use it. I don't know what that best practice is.

I have created a component which renders a button and needs to invoke an action in the parent component. What I have currently is the parent component with this in the template:

```
<my-button (clicked)="doSomething()"></my-button>
```

The parent component code has this function being fired:

```
doSomething() {
    // ..stuff happens
}
```

The problem is that the `myBtn` component is currently listening to a click event on a `button` element like this:

```
<button type="button" (click)="doClick()"></button>
```

And this function is used to fire the event itself (so here is the full button component code):

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-button",
  templateUrl: "./my-button.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./my-button.component.css"]
})
export class MyButtonComponent {

  constructor() {}
  
  @Input() someCondition: boolean;

  @Output() clicked = new EventEmitter();

  doClick() {
    if (!this.someCondition) {
      this.clicked.emit(); // NOT REACTIVE???
    }
  }
}
```

I recognise that the `doClick` logic is not the best practice, but I'm not sure what the best practice is.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't the best practice? Im not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but what you have looks fine.

Comment: I think your parent should be this `<my-button (depressed)="doSomething()"></my-button>`

Comment: (Element name corrected.) I have added the comment `NOT REACTIVE???` to the line which I believe to need improving. My current (limited) understanding is that this line should perhaps be emitting a value via a more reactive manner, though I don't know what that would be. Given the logic is to only emit a value if a certain condition is met, how could this be coded using a Subject and have the parent component listen for it?

Comment: you are listening to the wrong event on the parent, it should be `(depressed)` and not `(clicked)`.

Comment: Correct, but still is this how button components /should/ propagate values up to their parent? Should it be via state management or some other mechanism?

Comment: You can do it this way or using a service. It all depends on how the component/child work.

Comment: There is a design pattern called "Atomic Design", where there is a `atom`, `molecule`, `organism`, `template`, and `page`. When designing an atom you wouldn't use a service but you would do what you have above. When designing a molecule you can use both a service and an `@Output`. When using anything bigger I would use a service. This however is all an opinion though. https://atomicdesign.bradfrost.com/chapter-2/

Comment: you can use simply `<button type="button" (click)="condition && clicked.emit()"></button>` but I'm not pretty sure about "best practice"

Comment: I personally think your solution looks fine, but maybe pass the click event object too

Comment: Being new to the reactive mindset, looking at other code it seemed to me that directly calling a function (`emit`) to fire an event was wrong (bad style, at least.) So I've been looking for a more elegant (or 'reactive') form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best code I have come up with so far is this:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, Output, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { combineLatest, fromEvent, Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, filter, map, takeUntil, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: "my-button",
  templateUrl: "./my-button.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./my-button.component.css"]
})
export class MyButtonComponent {
  destroy$ = new Subject();

  constructor() {}

  @ViewChild("refreshBtn", { static: true }) clickerBtn: ElementRef;
  
  @Input() refreshState$: Observable<boolean>;

  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() refreshLabel: string;

  @Output() clicked = new EventEmitter();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.clickerBtn.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$), debounceTime(300), withLatestFrom(this.refreshState$))
      .subscribe(([_, refresh]) => !refresh && this.clicked.emit());
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

This works and, so far, is the "most reactive" code I can come up with.

Comment: What task are you trying to accomplish other than best practices? Maybe this solution is good, or we can give you a better one with a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Off-Topic: if you move your subscription to the template, you then don't have to unsubscribe/complete the request, as Angular will do that for you.

Comment: The task being achieved is as described in the question post: a reusable button component which fires an event to the parent in a reactive manner.

Comment: How could the subscription be moved to the template and still handle all the other operations like debounce and withLatestFrom?